# Guess the random number game

Tags: java, beginner, number-guessing-game

I have created the classic "guess the random number" game:

**Generator Interface**

```
 package ishan.guessingGame.randomNumberGenerators;

 public interface RandomNumber {

 public int generate();
}
```

**Generator Implementation**

```
package ishan.guessingGame.randomNumberGenerators;

import java.util.Random;

public class SimpleRandomNumberGenerator implements RandomNumber {

private int limit=50;

public SimpleRandomNumberGenerator(){

}
public SimpleRandomNumberGenerator(int limit){
    this.limit=limit;
}
@Override
public int generate() {

    return generateRandomNumber();
}

private int generateRandomNumber(){
    Random random=new Random();
    return random.nextInt(limit+1);
}
}
```

**Game interface**

```
package ishan.guessingGame.game;        

public interface Game {

public void startGame();
}
```

**A Game Impl**

```
package ishan.guessingGame.game;

import java.util.Scanner;

import ishan.guessingGame.randomNumberGenerators.RandomNumber;
import ishan.guessingGame.randomNumberGenerators.SimpleRandomNumberGenerator;

public class SimpleGuessingGame implements Game{

private int randomNumber;
private int difficultyLevel;
private Scanner scanner;
private RandomNumber random;
private int input=999;

public SimpleGuessingGame(){
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

@Override
public void startGame() {
    init();
    play();
    endGame();
}

private void init(){

    System.out.println("Enter The Difficulty : 1 = Easy , 2 = Moderate , 3 =Difficult");

    String difficulty;
    difficulty=scanner.next();

    if(!checkInputIsNumber(difficulty, true)){
        endGame();
    }

    difficultyLevel=Integer.parseInt(difficulty);

    if(difficultyLevel == 1){
        random=new SimpleRandomNumberGenerator();
    }
    else if (difficultyLevel == 2){
        random=new SimpleRandomNumberGenerator(100);
    }
    else{
        random=new SimpleRandomNumberGenerator(200);
    }
    randomNumber=random.generate();
}

private void play(){
    System.out.println("Input any character to exit..");

    while(true){
        System.out.println(" Guess The Number");
        String tempInput=scanner.next();

        if(!checkInputIsNumber(tempInput , false)){
            endGame();
        }

        input=Integer.parseInt(tempInput);
        if(input==randomNumber){
            System.out.println("You won.Bye!!");
            endGame();
        }
        else if(input > randomNumber){
            System.out.println("Easy there. Guess a smaller Number");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Pick a larger one");
        }
    }
}


private boolean checkInputIsNumber(String input , boolean checkForDifficulty) {

    if(checkForDifficulty){
        if(input.matches("^[0-3]")){
            return true;
        }
    }

    else if (input.matches("^[0-9]*")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void endGame() {
    scanner.close();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

**Main class**

```
package ishan.apps;

import ishan.guessingGame.game.Game;
import ishan.guessingGame.game.SimpleGuessingGame;

public class MainApplication {

public static void main(String a[]){
    Game game=new SimpleGuessingGame();
    game.startGame();
}
}
```

I have tried to code to interfaces and would like to get suggestions around that area and my code in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the class **SimpleRandomNumberGenerator** :

1. Having `generate()` delegate to a private method is, in this case a bit overkill.
2. You create a new `Random` instance for each method invocation. This makes the `SimpleRandomNumberGenerator` not genrating an even distirbution of random numbers. Make it a private final field initialized at the declaration or in the constructor.
3. Good use of coding to interfaces, by hiding the implementation details behind an interface.

Then **MainApplication** :

1. Spot on : kept simple this class' responsibility is to wire everything together and kick things off.

And now for the meat **SimpleGuessingGame** :

1. Several fields of this class can be truned into local variables in the one method that uses them : `difficultyLevel`, `random` and `input`.
2. `startGame()` is well implemented, easy to read.
3. On the whole the class has at least 2 responsibilities :

   - handling user interaction
   - keeping track of game state

   That is too much. Imagine here you'd want to be able to play the same game but with a graphical UI.

   So we want to split this into more classes using interfaces to hide implementation from one another.

   I would suggest using these two interfaces :

   ```
   interface UserInteraction {

       String askDifficulty();

       void close();

       String askToGuess();

       void showHowToEndMessage();

       void showWinMessage();

       void showGuessSmallerMessage();

       void showGuessLargerMessage();
   }


   interface GameState {

       Result guess(int guess);
   }

   public enum Result {

       CORRECT, GUESS_LARGER, GUESS_SMALLER
   }
   ```
4. `checkInputIsNumber()` should be split into two separate methods : one for the difficulty and one for the guesses. They can then be named more aptly to increase readability (boolean parameters say so little at the call site)
5. the loop in the `play()` method is implemented as an infinite loop, while it is obviously driven by the game state. Meanwhile `endGame()` quite harshly exits, this makes it harder to embed the game in a larger program. Only the MainApplication class should call `System.exit()`

There's more to do as a follow up on these remarks, but I'd start there.

Answer (score 3):

**Style**

- your indentation is off
- use more spaces (around `=` and `+`, before `{`, etc)

Just paste your code into any IDE, it can fix this easily for you, and it will make your code more readable.

**Wrapper Methods**

Whenever you have a method that doesn't do anything, but just calls another method, you can remove it.

Just copy the code of `generateRandomNumber` into `generate`.

**checkInputIsNumber if statement**

The if statements are a bit confusing. I would write it as:

```
    if (checkForDifficulty && input.matches("^[0-3]")) {
            return true;
    } else if (input.matches("^[0-9]*")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Or even just:

```
return (checkForDifficulty && input.matches("^[0-3]")) || input.matches("^[0-9]*");
```

But I would actually make more methods out of this, because it seems like two different activities (check if it can be parsed as integer, and check if the integer is below 3). I would create a `isInt` method (or just use a try block), and then a `isBelow(number, numberToCheck)` method (or not. if you separate the functionality, it becomes easier to see that the functionality actually doesn't need to be extracted to a method).

**Declare Variables in smallest scope**

You should always declare variables in the smallest scope possible, that way a reader only has to have them in mind when they actually matter.

`difficultyLevel` for example is defined at class level, but only used in `init`.

**Misc**

- you can make `random` a field in `SimpleRandomNumberGenerator` instead of creating a new object each time.
- just exiting on malformed input isn't very user friendly.
- using `50` as the default value for a random number seems quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**

Note that package names in Java should always have lower case. So `ishan.guessingGame.randomNumberGenerators` should be `ishan.guessinggame.randomNumbergenerators`.

**Overrides**

Why are you just returning another method here ?

> ```
> @Override public int generate() {
>
>     return generateRandomNumber(); 
> }
> ```

`generaeRandomNumber()` is not complex and from what I can understand of your code, is not called anywhere else, so you could just implement it directly in `generate`.

You did great with `startGame()`, with making 3 call to private methods. By using private method you encapsulate what you're doing and that is great.

**Random**

I'm no expert with the `Random` class. There is a lot of subtleties with generating random numbers. What you need to be aware is that generating a new `Random` for generating a new number can screw the randomness. You should declare a private `Random` instance and use it in your generate method.

**System.exit**

I would strongly advise you to stop using this method. It's drastic! When you will deal with more complex application, you will have resources that you will want to close gracefully ( a database, a GUI and etc). `System.exit()` does not leave place to cleanly stop the application.

Let the application finish normally! It's not the **responsibility** of the `Game` to determine if the application should stop!

Answer (score 2):

To add something that I believe the other answers missed, and is pretty important:

Inside `SimpleRandomNumberGenerator` you should, perhaps, impose some preconditions on the limit that gets passed. You might or might have not considered this, but `public int generate()` in your case throws an `IllegalArgumentException` (as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) also states) if the limit received in the constructor + 1 is not a positive integer. Perhaps you should let the clients know about it?